# How to create a border including a conditional logic element with css

Tags: css, wordpress, border, gravity-forms-plugin

I am a rookie when it comes to css and I am currenty using a custom css plugin in WordPress for my gravity forms submission form. Included in that form is a conditional logic element attached to a selection field. "External Links" shows up when you select YES. I was hoping to create a border around both the selection ("Does your project use links") and the conditional element "External links". I am using this code currently

```
#field_4_19, #field_4_21 { border: 1px solid #D8AB4C;}
```

[and what I get is this result where two seperate borders are allocated to the two different elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoywO.png)

Has anyone a suggestion how I can alter the code so that both elements are wrapped in one border?

Thank you in advance.
O

Comment: i suggest you share html also that might help to get you better answers

Answer (score 0):

Without you providing the HTML structure it is difficult to give you a very good answer, but the easier way to accomplish what you're talking about here is to wrap both elements in a `div` and apply your border around that. Then you're structure would look like this if the there is only 1 element:

```
<div class="MyWrapper">
    <input id="field_4_19">
</div>
```

and like this if there are two

```
<div class="MyWrapper">
    <input id="field_4_19">
    <input id="field_4_21">
</div>
```

Your CSS would then just look like

```
.MyWrapper { border: 1px solid #D8AB4C;}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - since I want to make these changes to an individual page, the HTML would be pasted into the regular text editor of said page in wordpress, correct? I am using wp add custom css, which has a corresponding individual custom css editor right underneath (--here I enter all css codes).